# Getting issues in localhost URLs

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I'm adding links to Wordpress Localhost as "/about" but it doesn't show correctly on front end. My site URL is something like "http://localhost/abc" and the url how it shows is "http://localhost/about", but how actually it should be displayed as "http://localhost/abc/about".

It should dynamically add links with current url

Comment: If you're using a machine with an apache server instance you set up yourself, make sure you enable the `mod_rewrite` module. On UNIX-like OSs, `sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo apachectl restart`.

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1

Review `wp_options` table and in that `home` option should be **http://localhost/wordpress**

[image: See screenshot]

### Step 2

Check any pluin or theme is causing the redirection. Debug with disabling
active plugins or active theme.

### Step 3

If Step 1 & Step 2 not worked you need to recheck the `.htacess` file of any file that rewriting your urls to specific
url. [Read more about
debuging](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#:%7E:text=WP_DEBUG%20is%20a%20PHP%20constant,(%20%27WP_DEBUG%27%2C%20true%20)%3B)